# Utilizando o comando FOR

Tags: c, string, for

Estou desenvolvendo resolvendo questões em Linguagem C. A questão pede:

> Um palíndromo é uma palavra ou frase que tenha a propriedade de poder ser lida tanto da direita para a esquerda como da esquerda para a direita. Por exemplo, as strings "aaaaa", "1221", "bbaabb" são palíndromos, entretanto a string "chef" não é um palíndromo porque se lermos da direita para a esquerda, obtemos "fehc" que não é a mesma coisa que "chef".
>
> Ignore as diferenças entre maiúsculas e minúsculas.
>
> Para os casos onde é dada uma frase, você deve ignorar os espaços. Por
>   exemplo, a frase "A base do teto desaba" é considerada um palíndromo.
>   Ao lê-la da direita para a esquerda, você obterá: "abased otet od esab
>   A".
>
> Perceba que, com exceção do espaço, a sequência de caracteres é a
>   mesma da frase original. Faça um programa que indique se uma string
>   dada é um palíndromo ou não.

Ao escolher 3, o meu código me permite digitar apenas 2 vezes e emite 1 resultado

[image: Erro da quantidade de casos analisados]

E o meu código é este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
char nome[255], inversa[255];
int i, qtd, resultado;

scanf( "%i", &qtd );
    for ( i = 0; i < qtd; i++ )

        gets (nome);

        strcpy (inversa, nome);

        strrev(inversa);

        resultado = strcmp (nome, inversa);

        if (resultado == 0) {
            printf("SIM");
        } else {
            printf("NAO");
        }
    return 0;
}
```

O site dá um exemplo da entrada e de sua respectiva saída:

[image: Exemplo da entrada e saída]

Onde está o erro do meu programa e poderia dar uma breve explicação?

Comment: Além do erro é um código bem ineficiente, e a resposta postada também é ineficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Como o próprio enunciado diz, você precisa ignorar tanto os espaços, e as diferenças entre maiúsculas e minusculas, então antes de comparar as strings você poderia normaliza-las:

```
char nome[255], normalizado[255], inversa[255];
int i, j, k, tam, qtd, resultado;

// ...

gets(nome);

// Encontra o tamanho da string de entrada
tam = strlen(nome);

// Percorre o nome para gerar uma nova string normalizada
for (j = 0, k = 0; j < tam; j++) {
    // Se o caractere for diferente de um espaço...
    if (nome[j] != ' ') {
        // Converte para maiúsculo e o adiciona a nova string
        normalizado[k++] = toupper(nome[j]);
    }
}
// Adiciona um null terminator ao fim da string
normalizado[k] = '\0';
```

Agora basta reverter a string normalizada e a comparar.

---

Perceba também que no seu código você esqueceu de abrir as chaves no seu laço for.